# Firebase Offline Capabilities and addListenerForSingleValueEvent

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Whenever I use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` with `setPersistenceEnabled(true)`, I only manage to get a local offline copy of `DataSnapshot` and **NOT** the updated `DataSnapshot` from the server.

However, if I use `addValueEventListener` with `setPersistenceEnabled(true)`, I can get the latest copy of `DataSnapshot` from the server.

Is this normal for `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` as it only searches `DataSnapshot` locally (offline) and removes its listener after successfully retrieving `DataSnapshot` **ONCE** (either offline or online)?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

**Update (2021)**: There *is* a new method call ([`get` on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#get()) and [`getData` on iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DatabaseQuery#/c:objc(cs)FIRDatabaseQuery(im)getDataWithCompletionBlock:)) that implement the behavior you'll like want: it first tries to get the latest value from the server, and only falls back to the cache when it can't reach the server. The recommendation to use persistent listeners still applies, but at least there's a cleaner option for getting data once even when you have local caching enabled.

---

## How persistence works

The Firebase client keeps a copy of all data you're actively listening to in memory. Once the last listener disconnects, the data is flushed from memory.

If you enable disk persistence in a Firebase Android application with:

```
Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

The Firebase client will keep a local copy (on disk) of all data that the app has recently listened to.

## What happens when you attach a listener

Say you have the following `ValueEventListener`:

```
ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        System.out.println(snapshot.getValue());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        // No-op
    }
};
```

When you add a `ValueEventListener` to a location:

```
ref.addValueEventListener(listener); 
// OR
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);
```

If the value of the location is in the local disk cache, the Firebase client will invoke `onDataChange()` immediately for that value from the local cache. If will then also initiate a check with the server, to ask for any updates to the value. It *may* subsequently invoke `onDataChange()` again if there has been a change of the data on the server since it was last added to the cache.

## What happens when you use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`

When you add a single value event listener to the same location:

```
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);
```

The Firebase client will (like in the previous situation) immediately invoke `onDataChange()` for the value from the local disk cache. It will *not* invoke the `onDataChange()` any more times, even if the value on the server turns out to be different. Do note that updated data still will be requested and returned on subsequent requests.

This was covered previously in [How does Firebase sync work, with shared data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260450/how-does-work-firebase-sync-with-share-data)

## Solution and workaround

The best solution is to use [`addValueEventListener()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#addValueEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)), instead of a single-value event listener. A regular value listener will get both the immediate local event and the potential update from the server.

A second solution is to use the new [`get` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#get()) (introduced in early 2021), which doesn't have this problematic behavior. Note that this method always tries to first fetch the value from the server, so it will take longer to completely. If your value never changes, it might still be better to use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` (but you probably wouldn't have ended up on this page in that case).

As a workaround you can also [call `keepSynced(true)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-prioritizing-the-local-cache) on the locations where you use a single-value event listener. This ensures that the data is updated whenever it changes, which drastically improves the chance that your single-value event listener will see the current value.

Comment: Thanks for perfect illustration. But keepSynced(true) and addValueEventListener will keep an open connection all the time. In contrast to keepSynced(false) and addListenerForSingleValueEvent will allow the firebase to disconnect after sometime. How can i force one time manual update?

Comment: What an unconvenient behavior, it makes testing almost impossible.

Comment: Calling `keepSynced(true)` and then using `.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);` doesn't work when the app is opened for the first time after a database change. It takes opening the app twice before the change is registered.

Comment: @Drew it actually works when you do one call after "keepSynced". Create query, set keepSynced, addValue for example and onCompleted keepValue false to avoid synching all the time. Then data is refreshed (didn't check if it works each time like it needs to). The other solution which seems to work is my answer in this post

Comment: so if I use singleValueEvent listener, it will always return the same initial value, never the update?

Comment: A warning when using keepSynced: it can cause a huge drain on your bandwidth, with the associated costs. See the following for a practical explanation: https://pamartinezandres.com/lessons-learnt-the-hard-way-using-firebase-realtime-database-c609b52b9afb

Comment: I worked with that team recently to figure out where the bandwidth usage came from. Synchronizing too much data definitely contributed, but not nearly as much as they initially thought. A large part of their traffic came from the overhead of establishing an SSL connection upon every app startup. Especially on mobile apps (more than on web apps) that are started frequently and then used briefly, this becomes a major contributor to bandwidth usage. There is no way to prevent need for establishing this SSL connection, but it's definitely something to keep in mind.

Comment: See my working solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486417/firebase-offline-capabilities-and-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent/59524932#59524932

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen getData is returning the parent path, for some reason, until I restart the app(iOS) with both keepSynced true and false. I figured the best way would be to use a value listener. The problem is that I don't know whether the returned value is from cache or a remote one so my app would get jumpy if I receive multiple responses. And I can't really know if the remote value matches the cache since I'd get no callback if that happens so the only solution is to do a random delay waiting for the remote value to come but that really depends on the connection and the size of the object.

Comment: @Mercurial I'm using the getData method and it works perfectly. I'm not sure why it would return the parent path. You need to put it in the exact same place as the observer was used.i.e I replaced this: 
myQuery.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { ... 
with this 
myQuery.getData{ ....
and that worked for me, now i'm getting the server value, which is what I needed after using runTransaction to update. No need to use delays.

Answer (score 2):

So I have a working solution for this. All you have to do is use ValueEventListener and remove the listener after 0.5 seconds to make sure you've grabbed the updated data by then if needed. Realtime database has very good latency so this is safe. See safe code example below;

```
public class FirebaseController {

private DatabaseReference mRootRef;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

private FirebaseController() {
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);

    mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
}

public static FirebaseController getInstance() {
    if (sInstance == null) {
        sInstance = new FirebaseController();
    }
    return sInstance;
}
```

Then some method you'd have liked to use "addListenerForSingleEvent";

```
public void getTime(final OnTimeRetrievedListener listener) {
    DatabaseReference ref = mRootRef.child("serverTime");
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (listener != null) {
                // This can be called twice if data changed on server - SO DEAL WITH IT!
                listener.onTimeRetrieved(dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class));
            }
            // This can be called twice if data changed on server - SO DEAL WITH IT!
            removeListenerAfter2(ref, this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            removeListenerAfter2(ref, this);
        }
    });
}

// ValueEventListener version workaround for addListenerForSingleEvent not working.
private void removeListenerAfter2(DatabaseReference ref, ValueEventListener listener) {
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            HelperUtil.logE("removing listener", FirebaseController.class);
            ref.removeEventListener(listener);
        }
    }, 500);
}

// ChildEventListener version workaround for addListenerForSingleEvent not working.
private void removeListenerAfter2(DatabaseReference ref, ChildEventListener listener) {
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            HelperUtil.logE("removing listener", FirebaseController.class);
            ref.removeEventListener(listener);
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

Even if they close the app before the handler is executed, it will be removed anyways.
Edit: this can be abstracted to keep track of added and removed listeners in a HashMap using reference path as key and datasnapshot as value.  You can even wrap a fetchData method that has a boolean flag for "once" if this is true it would do this workaround to get data once, else it would continue as normal.
You're Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can create transaction and abort it, then onComplete will be called when online (nline data) or offline (cached data)

I previously created function which worked only if database got connection lomng enough to do synch. I fixed issue by adding timeout. I will work on this and test if this works. Maybe in the future, when I get free time, I will create android lib and publish it, but by then it is the code in kotlin:

```
/**
     * @param databaseReference reference to parent database node
     * @param callback callback with mutable list which returns list of objects and boolean if data is from cache
     * @param timeOutInMillis if not set it will wait all the time to get data online. If set - when timeout occurs it will send data from cache if exists
     */
    fun readChildrenOnlineElseLocal(databaseReference: DatabaseReference, callback: ((mutableList: MutableList<@kotlin.UnsafeVariance T>, isDataFromCache: Boolean) -> Unit), timeOutInMillis: Long? = null) {

        var countDownTimer: CountDownTimer? = null

        val transactionHandlerAbort = object : Transaction.Handler { //for cache load
            override fun onComplete(p0: DatabaseError?, p1: Boolean, data: DataSnapshot?) {
                val listOfObjects = ArrayList<T>()
                data?.let {
                    data.children.forEach {
                        val child = it.getValue(aClass)
                        child?.let {
                            listOfObjects.add(child)
                        }
                    }
                }
                callback.invoke(listOfObjects, true)
            }

            override fun doTransaction(p0: MutableData?): Transaction.Result {
                return Transaction.abort()
            }
        }

        val transactionHandlerSuccess = object : Transaction.Handler { //for online load
            override fun onComplete(p0: DatabaseError?, p1: Boolean, data: DataSnapshot?) {
                countDownTimer?.cancel()
                val listOfObjects = ArrayList<T>()
                data?.let {
                    data.children.forEach {
                        val child = it.getValue(aClass)
                        child?.let {
                            listOfObjects.add(child)
                        }
                    }
                }
                callback.invoke(listOfObjects, false)
            }

            override fun doTransaction(p0: MutableData?): Transaction.Result {
                return Transaction.success(p0)
            }
        }
```

In the code if time out is set then I set up timer which will call transaction with abort. This transaction will be called even when offline and will provide online or cached data (in this function there is really high chance that this data is cached one).
Then I call transaction with success. `OnComplete` will be called ONLY if we got response from firebase database. We can now cancel timer (if not null) and send data to callback.

This implementation makes dev 99% sure that data is from cache or is online one.

If you want to make it faster for offline (to don't wait stupidly with timeout when obviously database is not connected) then check if database is connected before using function above:

```
DatabaseReference connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
    if (connected) {
      System.out.println("connected");
    } else {
      System.out.println("not connected");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
    System.err.println("Listener was cancelled");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When workinkg with persistence enabled, I counted the times the listener received a call to onDataChange() and stoped to listen at 2 times. Worked for me, maybe helps:

```
private int timesRead;
private ValueEventListener listener;
private DatabaseReference ref;

private void readFB() {
    timesRead = 0;
    if (ref == null) {
        ref = mFBDatabase.child("URL");
    }

    if (listener == null) {
        listener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //process dataSnapshot

                timesRead++;
                if (timesRead == 2) {
                    ref.removeEventListener(listener);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        };
    }
    ref.removeEventListener(listener);
    ref.addValueEventListener(listener);
}
```

Comment: If the local cached data is the same as the server data, onDataChange will be called only once, thus "ref.removeEventListener(listener);" won't be executed

Comment: See my working solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486417/firebase-offline-capabilities-and-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent/59524932#59524932