# Does observeSingleEventOfType:FEventTypeValue return data from local cache

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When my IOS app starts up it checks Firebase for some data about currency exchange rates.  The problem is that it seems like it's returning the exchange rates from the local cache (I have disk persistence enabled).  Is this expected behavior?  There are some obvious work-arounds but I just want to understand the limitations of observeSingleEvent - basically that it's not to be used to get the latest data from Firebase.

Comment: Yes, that is expected behavior. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486417/firebase-offline-capabilities-and-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent

Comment: OK.  But it's a little confusing.  In your other stack overflow answer you say "The Firebase client will keep a local copy of all data that is actively listened to."  But I only have a single event listener on this data - which I thought meant that it was not actively listened to.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen would greatly appreciate if you could comment on the above.  Is it expected behavior that once you do an observeSingleEvent forValue that Firebase will use the local cache for that data going forward?  Unless I turn disk persistence off I can't seem to find any way to force a read from the server.  This is on IOS.