# offline Firebase database not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, persistence

> I want my app to save data locally offline. whenever i reopen the app while **their is no Internet**. It should work

in onCreate of Application I call

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

offline `capablilites` are working as long as the app is started while having internet. And if I close the app and restart **it the data is not synched**.

also tried

```
keepSynched(true);
```

But as long as you kill the app. **It loses connection and no offline data is available**. How to do persistance data in android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase offline capabilities as cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38778680/firebase-offline-capabilities-as-cache)

Answer (score 4):

you have to call `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);` in every where that you want your retrieved data to be stored locally. Therefore, you should create a helper class like this:

```
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class FirebaseUtils {
    private static DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
    private static FirebaseDatabase database;
    public static DatabaseReference getDatabaseRef() {
        if (mDatabaseRef == null) {
            getDatabase();
            mDatabaseRef = database.getReference();
            // ...
        }
        return mDatabaseRef;
    }

    public static FirebaseDatabase getDatabase() {
        if (database == null) {
            database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            database.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
            // ...
        }
        return database;
    }
}
```

Then, in your activity and fragment and other places where you want to do your database stuff, you initialize the DatabaseReference object like this:

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private DatabaseReference mPlaceRef;

....

mDatabase = FirebaseUtils.getDatabaseRef();
mPlaceRef = mDatabase .child("places");

...
```

Comment: you have choosen sb with bad reputation to reply to,this hasnt marked as answer even once

Comment: @D.'s thanks buddy. Thats okay. at least i have you who care about my effort. appreciate it

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. Firebase throws this exception:

com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Calls to setPersistenceEnabled() must be made before any other usage of FirebaseDatabase instance

Answer (score 0):

`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true)` should only be called once during start or initialization of your app.

I tested this in iOS and it works well, but in android it is not working.

Comment: The OP asked how to do persistance in an Android env. Would you happen to know _why_ it's not working there?