# Data out of sync using same account on different devices

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When the same data is accessed on different devices, the data is not consistent between the two.

For example, if one user updates a node of data from one device, it is not reflected on another device querying the same data via **observeSingleEvent**.

Should I be using a different query than this?

Comment: My guess is that you're looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486417/firebase-offline-capabilities-and-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent/34487195#34487195 (the question is about Android, but the behavior is exactly the same on iOS). But without seeing the minimal code that reproduces the problem, it is hard to say more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it depends on your exact setup, but my guess is that using `observeSingleEventOfType` is the problem. That means the your app observes an event once, and then basically ignores any future events, including future updates. So if your app works something like this...

1. First app starts up
2. First app uses `observeSingleEventOfType` to populate its initial data
3. Second app updates a node of data

...that first app won't update its data. The single event has already been "used up" with that initial call.

If your expecting your app to keep updating your data, I'd probably recommend trying out `observeEventOfType` methods and see if that addresses your issue.

Comment: I am using observeEventOfType with the FIRDataEventType .value for my query and everything looks to be updating and observing changes to the JSON. Thanks