# Firebase checking if exists returns false where it should return true

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to check if a user with a particular email exists or not. The user with this email is in the database so the check should have returned true instead of false.

Here's the schema:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
final DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
userRef.orderByChild("email").equalTo("rafael.adel20@gmail.com").limitToFirst(1).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        System.out.println(dataSnapshot); //returns { key = users, value = null }
        if(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) {
            //user already exists (Never executed)
        } else {
            //user doesn't exists (Always executed)
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Do you see any different behaviour if you use `addValueEventListener` instead of `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`?

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly That's weird, using `addValueEventListener` works. But I wonder why ?

Comment: I've seen sometimes where it returns cached version (are you calling `setPersistenceEnabled(true)`?).  Following has better explanation - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486417/firebase-offline-capabilities-and-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly Aha, Interesting. Please post your answer so I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `setPersistenceEnabled(true)` is called, use of  `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` can cause local cached version of data to be returned rather than latest version from server (whereas calling `addValueEventListener` will ensure you get latest version).  Another approach, if using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` is to call `query.keepSynced(true);`

Comment: Great answer John. I wrote up a more extensive explanation of this behavior a while ago. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486417/firebase-offline-capabilities-and-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent/34487195#34487195