# Firebase observeSingleEvent not invoking callback function ios

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, promisekit

I have a situation in which my Firebase reference is not invoking the callback for observeSingleEvent.

```
 let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

 FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapShot) in                    
           //code here not called
        }) { (error) in
           //code here not called either
        }
```

In my case it appears the uid property which is coming from `FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid` is somehow being cached from a previous app installation when I'm switching between Firebase environments (building with different dev and staging .plist files.)

However, if I just add a random non existing string in place of uid the callback occurs as expected with an empty snapshot for a missing reference node.

I believe it's relevant to mention that I'm using synced Firebase references with persistanceEnabled = true.

I'm in a situation where I'm switching between environments and my app is hanging because promises are not being fulfilled or rejected because the results of by `observeSingleEvent` method call are never completing.

Comment: And I can confirm that the uid value is always a non nil uid-looking string

Comment: Since you've been using disk persistence, most likely there is an outdated value in the cache. The best way to not be affected by this caching behavior is to use a regular observer, disk persistence and `observeSingleEvent` don't mix well. See my explanation here (for Android, but the iOS client works the same way): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486417/firebase-offline-capabilities-and-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent/34487195#34487195

Comment: so, even switching to observe vs observeSingleEvent is still never firing that block of code. Same behavior as above. Should I expect the callback to call even if it's running against an outdated cache?

Comment: Attaching a listener to a location will synchronize the data for that location and thus update the persistent cache for that location.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen are you saying that even if I have a FirebaseReference instance that I call keepSynced(true) meathod on, it still won't synchronize unless there is an actual listener on that reference?

Comment: Calling `keepSynced(true)` puts an invisible listener on that location. So the result will be the same: your cache will be kept up to date.