# Read Existing data once from Firebase in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wanted to read the existing data once from firebase and I don't want to listen further changes in the firebase.. I used the below code but neither if nor else statement executing. i also tried with observe api instead of observeSingleEvent but it is not working.

```
func readData(empid : Int)
        {
            var data  =  ["name":"","address":"","age":0] as [String : Any]
            let ref: DatabaseReference! =  Database.database().reference()

            ref.child("Org").child("emp") .child(String(empid)).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                if(snapshot.exists())
                {
                    data = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, Any>
                    print("data    ",data)

                }
                else
                {
                    print("no data")
                }

            })
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#read_data_once):

> In some cases you may want a callback to be called once and then immediately removed, such as when initializing a UI element that you don't expect to change. You can use the observeSingleEventOfType method to simplify this scenario: the event callback added triggers once and then does not trigger again.
>
> **This is useful for data that only needs to be loaded once and isn't expected to change frequently** or require active listening. For instance, the blogging app in the previous examples uses this method to load a user's profile when they begin authoring a new post

*observeSingleEvent* will use the offline cache and will not update as soon as there are changes on the database. Thats why you are not getting the moste up to date data. I had this problem before and I removed the observer immediately after I got the data.

You could use something like this:

```
let observer:FIRDatabaseHandle!
observer = ref.child("Org").child("emp") .child(String(empid)).observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    removeObserverWithHandle(observer)
    //I am not sure if that's the right syntax 
    //but there is a func to remove an observer handle. See the link below
})
```

From the [Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#detach_listeners):

> Observers don't automatically stop syncing data when you leave a ViewController. **If an observer isn't properly removed, it continues to sync data to local memory.** When an observer is no longer needed, remove it by passing the associated FIRDatabaseHandle to the removeObserverWithHandle method.

So you should always remove an observer if you don't need it anymore.

[Also see this stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42430734/firebase-ios-snapshot-isnt-updated-but-database-is)