# Firebase persistence enabled leaving expired data

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've recently turned on offline persistence for my Firebase database in my iPhone app:

`FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true`

When reading the data from a database reference then going into the Firebase console and deleting that data, the next time I read from that reference the deleted entries are still there. Is this a side effect of having persistence enabled in my Firebase app? I'm reading the data in this manner:

```
let petRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("pets").child(pet)
petRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
   ...
```

Should I always use `.keepSynced(true)` on references to not have this happen?

Comment: Firebase Database's disk persistence doesn't mix well with single-value event listeners. See [my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486417/firebase-offline-capabilities-and-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent) for details. In this case `keepSynced(true)` might work, but as a general rule: use regular `observe` listeners when using disk persistence.

Comment: Thanks Frank. Is using `keepSynced(true)` expensive? I plan on having 2 or 3 references synced for each user of my application.

Comment: Keeping a location synced is as expensive as the data changes at that location, plus some minor overhead for attaching the listener.