# keepSync() vs observe() with Firebase offline persistance

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want users to have the most recently updated values for a ref of my database but the reading of those values to be quick as my UI depends on them. For this reason I've set `FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true` to allow for data to be cached locally, as well as having my ref's synced using `FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("usersRef").keepSynced(true)`.

After reading Frank van Puffelen's [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486417/firebase-offline-capabilities-and-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent) on how to keep values synced but also cached it appears that another option would be to use `observe()` in iOS (or `addValueEventListener()` for android) to accomplish this same thing.

What are the advantages to using the `observe()` method as compared to `keepSynced(true)`. Is one faster than the other? Does one have more overhead? Is one more "accurate" than the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `keepSynced(true)` on a node, keeps an active listener on that node. There isn't more to it then that.

Comment: So they're the same pretty much I guess