# Receiving incorrect data from Firebase through SingleEventListener on Android except for when I reinstall the app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using a single value event listener to check a date stored in Firebase. If the date from Firebase is after the date I have stored on the phone of when the phones local database was last updated then the phones local database is updated.

I have it set to log the value that it gets from the database and when the app is just installed the value is correct but from then on if I change the value in the Firebase database the Android app continues to get the value from before it was changed.

For example:

Here is my code from the Android app:

```
DatabaseReference priceRef = mRootRef.child("Pricing");
DatabaseReference priceUpdatedRef = priceRef.child("Updated");
priceUpdatedRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              String dateString = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
              Log.d(TAG,"Firebase updated on: " + dateString);
              String lastUpdated = mSharedPreferences.getString("Date of last price table update", null);
              Log.d(TAG,"Local database updated on: " + lastUpdated);
              Date dateUpdated = sdfOrder.parse(dateString, new ParsePosition(0));
              Date dateLastUpdated = sdfOrder.parse(lastUpdated, new ParsePosition(0));
              if (dateUpdated.after(dateLastUpdated)) {
                 Log.d(TAG, "Price list has changed since last update. Updating now...");
                 DeletePriceLists();
                 UpdatePriceLists();
              } else {
                      Log.d(TAG, "Price list does not require updating");
                     }     
          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
          });
     }
```

The JSON in Firebase looks like this

```
"Pricing" : {
...
"Updated": "2017-08-26"
}
```

Say I install the app for the first time. I initially get this log because there is no record of when the phones local database was last updated and so it just does it anyway.

```
D/StartShiftActivity: No record of when price lists were last updated. Updating now...
```

Now say I just restart the app. I have it so that if there is a record of when the local database was updated it will log when Firebase was updated and log when the local database was updated. So now it logs:

```
08-26 16:28:43.431 14352-14352/? D/StartShiftActivity: Firebase updated on: 2017-08-26
08-26 16:28:43.432 14352-14352/? D/StartShiftActivity: Local database updated on: 2017-08-26
```

So far so good, it's getting the correct string from Firebase. But now say I restart the app and change it in Firebase so now the JSON is:

```
"Pricing" : {
...
"Updated": "2017-08-27"
}
```

It should now log that the price lists need to be updated but instead it logs:

```
08-26 16:32:18.655 15880-15880/? D/StartShiftActivity: Firebase updated on: 2017-08-26
08-26 16:32:18.655 15880-15880/? D/StartShiftActivity: Local database updated on: 2017-08-26
```

Why is it that the SingleValueEvent listener is still getting this old value instead of the new one? 
I have tried setting keepSync to true with no success.

The thing is, as soon as I reinstall the app it can get the new value with no problems. Is it being cached somewhere and so it's not bothering to check again even though it's connected? It just seems very strange.

EDIT: I also have disk persistence enabled so that if the user closes the app while offline, the queue of data to sync back to the database won't be lost and it will sync when the app is reopened. Not sure if that would be interfering with this.

Appreciate any insight into this.

Comment: You enable offline storage in your app for Firebase Data?

Comment: Do you mean disk persistence like documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities ? If so then yeah I have but I tried added keepSync(true) to the reference but the problem still occurs. It also has an active connection while getting these values

Comment: try without persistence method.

Comment: Most likely you're hitting an edge case between disk persistence and single-value listeners. See my explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486417/firebase-offline-capabilities-and-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent