# Possible to get latest data with observeSingleEvent + persistence enabled?

Tags: swift, firebase

I am trying to get some data from firebase. Any idea how can I get the latest data (not from cache) when I have persistence enabled? I tried keepSynced; I still get stale data. Is this the correct usage?

```
userRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("<path>")
userRef.keepSynced(true)
userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
   ...stale data here...
})
```

Or the only option is to use observe instead of observeSingleEvent? I don't like the fact that with observe I get the cache data first, and then the event triggers a second time with data from the server. So with observe, when I navigate to this screen, first I see a blank table, then I see the table with stale data, and then I see the table with latest data.

Thanks.

EDIT:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34487195/1373592 - 
This post says keeySynced should work. But it's not working for me. I would like to know if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Offline Capabilities and addListenerForSingleValueEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486417/firebase-offline-capabilities-and-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent)

Comment: `ObserveSingleEvent` will fetch the local cached data with persistence enabled. So if you want the updated value use `observeEvent` and skip the first value.

For more details : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486417/firebase-offline-capabilities-and-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent/34487195#34487195][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I retrieve some explanation, I think it might help you in your case :

> ObserveSingleEventType with keepSycned will not work if the Firebase
>   connection cannot be established on time. This is especially true
>   during appLaunch or in the appDelegate where there is a delay in the
>   Firebase connection and the cached result is given instead. **It will
>   also not work at times if persistence is enabled and
>   observeSingleEvent might give the cached data first.** In situations
>   like these, a continuous ObserveEventType is preferred and should be
>   used if you absolutely need fresh data.

I think you don't have the choice to use a continuous listener. But to avoid performance issues why you don't remove yourself your listeners when you don't it anymore.

Comment: Spend my last 3 hours writing all my methods from scratch just to find out that observeSingleEvent is causing this inconsistency!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to ALWAYS get latest data from firebase when persistence is turned on.  Use observe event, keepSynced on your ref and terminate listener if you don't want to keep it always.  After several trials, I came up with this and it is working.

```
func readFromFB() {
    let refHandle: DatabaseHandle?
    let ref: DatabaseReference? = firebase.child(nodeName)
    ref?.keepSynced(true)

    refHandle = ref!.observe(.value, with:
     { snapshot in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            for item in ((snapshot.value as! NSDictionary).allValues as Array) {
                //do whatever tasks
            }
        }
    })
    if let rf = ref {
        rf.removeObserver(withHandle: refHandle!)
    }
}
```

Comment: not working with exit() as well same the old data fetch