# which is the best approach to implement app that work online and offline?

Tags: android, json, sqlite, android-volley, android-contentprovider

I have an application that work on internet access only and I want to impliment it to work also in offline. And when there is internet access should sychronize data to the server

Comment: Check out this answer... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486417/firebase-offline-capabilities-and-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent

Comment: Thanks.. is there a link for resources that I can read for more understanding

Comment: You can refer this code. https://github.com/puf/firebase-offlinequeries-android

Answer (score 1):

Go through Priority Job Queue. While offline Store your API calls In Job Queue. And fire them When The internet is Available.

Answer (score 0):

You have two solution :

- You can create your own synchronisation  service ( can be complexe )
- You can use [couchbase](https://www.couchbase.com) it's a nosql database with a "sync gateway" which allow you to easilly sync between device