# Can I force observeSingleEvent from online instead of using the cache (Firebase)?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to force a observeSingleEvent from online by skipping the cache?

I have Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true and keepSynced = true. I generally want to use the cache but for this one task I want to force the data to be fetched from online.

Comment: Using disk persistence and `observeSingleEvent` don't mix well. If you want the latest version, you should use regular `observe`. See my longer explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486417/firebase-offline-capabilities-and-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent/34487195#34487195

Comment: Thank you so much Frank. Is there no possibility to add any parameters to the observeSingleEvent function to ignore the cached data, or to invoke something like ingnoreCache = true?

Comment: Nope. If you want the latest, find a way to use a regular observer, or don't use disk persistence/keep synced.

Comment: Thank you Frank!