# firebase database does not update local data

Tags: c#, android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am having a wired problem. My Database is not updating its local data. 
I use Unity3D with C# and deploying for Android.

I set

```
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.SetPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

and everything works just fine in the editor, because caching is not available anyways in editor.

Going on Android, when I install the App it downloads all the data correctly. Once I set ne data, it gets also saved in the cloud online but once I want to access the data again, it still has the old data that was created on app init. Even if I restart the App it does not update the local data. Therefor the local data and the cloud data get async.

I am a little confused, because the connection is available, I can write data to cloud I can access them if there is no local data available but it will not update.

If I go to Android App Info and delete all App-Data it downloads the entire firebase again but keeps it not sync.

Can anyone help me on that problem?
Thanks a lot and best regards,

Luke

Comment: I removed SetPersistenceEnabled(true); and it fetches data now correctly. I am really confused. It saves data correctly online but not locally and reads data from local data but not from online (if there is a connection)...What am I doing wrong?

Comment: oh and FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference.KeepSynced(true); does not help either

Comment: None of the code you shared reads or writes any data, so it's hard to see where you're going wrong. My best guess is that you're using single value event listeners, which don't work well with offline persistence. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486417/firebase-offline-capabilities-and-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent/34487195

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link. So to I get it right, data are written to the database online and not locally and I need an event listener to get the newest data back for local use, eventhough I wrote the data by myself? I did not post the writing because its no magic at all: 

Dictionary<string, object> updateElement = new Dictionary<string, object>();
updateElement.Add("iCurrentLevel/"+iPosition.ToString(),10000);

m_dbReference.Child("users/" + UserID).UpdateChildrenAsync(updateElement);

Comment: None of it is magic, it's all just code. But without seeing the [minimal, complete code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we're just guessing at what the problem is. I could well have guessed wrong in my previous comment, hence asking for an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).