# Flutter Firebase realtime once().then() doesn't get updated when rerun

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

Flutter Firebase realtime once().then() doesn't get updated when rerun

when I use once.then to read data if I run it again it won't update variables or give out null

Comment: cause this has happened many times at random. so I was questioning is once.then is the issue. like it happens at certain nodes and If I create new node it won't happen until later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `once()` method does precisely what its name implies: it reads the data once, and doesn't monitor for updates. As the [documentation](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/Query/once.html) says:

> Listens for a single value event and then stops listening.

To get realtime update, use one of the `on...` streams such as [`onValue`](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/Query/onValue.html) which:

> Fires when the data at this location is updated.

Comment: my issue is when I run once() method and then update the value and I re run the once() method it will still hold on the previous value

Comment: It's because you didn't change the data in server side. You just edited it locally!

Comment: will I am always looking at firebase dashboard and it's changed there

Comment: Did you enable disk persistence by any chance?

Comment: oooooh thank you , I did it following some instruction for something and forgot it.
deleting it fixed it.

Comment: Yeah, [disk persistence and `once()` don't mix well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486417/firebase-offline-capabilities-and-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent/34487195), since `once()` eagerly returns the local result, and you probably want to know the result from the server. That's something we changed in the Cloud Firestore API, where `get()` waits for the result from the server by default.