# firebase Keepsync(true) does not update the data

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

as the title, even I use Keepsync(true) before query but **firebase** always get wrong value ( the previous value )

this is my code :

```
    ROOT_REF.child(CHILD_SETTINGS).child(Member.getUser_id())
                        .child(getMyUID()).keepSynced(true);

                ROOT_REF.child(CHILD_SETTINGS)
                            .child(Member.getUser_id()).child(getMyUID())
                            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                    if (!dataSnapshot.hasChild(NO_MAKING_GROUP_SETTING))
                                        validList.add(Member);
                                    else unvalidList.add(Member);

                                    if (validList.size()+unvalidList.size()==mMemberToCheck.size()) {

                                        mValidCallBack.OnCallBack(validList);
                                        mUnValidCallBack.OnCallBack(unvalidList);

                                    }

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });
```

this is the update value code:

```
ROOT_REF.child(CHILD_SETTINGS)
                    .child(getMyUID()).child(user_to_prevent)
                    .child(NO_MAKING_GROUP_SETTING)
                    .setValue(true);

// remove when I want to allow user to notify me 

   ROOT_REF.child(CHILD_SETTINGS)
                    .child(getMyUID()).child(user_to_allow)
                    .child(NO_MAKING_GROUP_SETTING)
                    .removeValue();
```

this is the database

[image]

**Update :** I think this post can help : [Firebase Offline Capabilities and addListenerForSingleValueEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486417/firebase-offline-capabilities-and-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent)

Comment: Please add your database structure and indicate what is the exact data that you want to get.

Comment: I updated the post. When I remove or change the value. Firebase still get the previous value instead of the new value

Comment: What do you mean "get the previous value instead of the new value"?

Comment: it meant it is not get updated. for example : I exit app and set the value to "false" and them re-open it. instead of "false" , it return "true" <- the previous value

Comment: Where in your code are you chaning the value from false to true?

Comment: let me update . it just a ```setValue``` code

Comment: It's just a `setValue()` that exist where?

Comment: what do you meant ? I updated the post

Comment: In which part of your code are you using `setValue()`?

Comment: the second one of this post

Comment: I see that, I was asking in which part of your code in your project.

Comment: I dont understand what exactly you want me to do. my use case is that I need to check a user is valid or not, if the user does not have child ```NO_MAKING_GROUP_SETTING``` that user is valid else is not.