# how to stop auto reload firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

how do I stop or bypass the auto reload in Firebase Realtime Database, I want to manually reload the data. for instance, I want to use UIRefresh controller instead of using firebase cache reload

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do.  Please edit the question to show the code that's not working the way you expect, explain what it is actually doing instead, and what you would like to happen that's different that your observations.

Comment: It wasn’t a  Piece  of non working code, I couldn’t find away to stop the auto reload of firebase.

Comment: That still sounds like code that doesn't work the way you expect.  Please post all relevant code when posting on Stack Overflow, so we can see what you're working with.

Comment: its alright, I was able to fix it with a boolean, thank for the help though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to only load data once, and not automatically get notified of changes, you can use the `observeSingleEvent` methods.

Also see the documentation on [reading data once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#read_data_once), which contains the following example:

> ```
> let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
> ref.child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
>   // Get user value
>   let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
>   let username = value?["username"] as? String ?? ""
>   let user = User(username: username)
>
>  // ...
>   }) { (error) in
>     print(error.localizedDescription)
> }
> ```

The above example reads the data of `users/$userID` once, either from the server or from the local cache. A note on that last aspect: you shouldn't combine `observeSingleEvent` with [enabling disk persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#section-disk-persistence) as they don't work well together as explained in [Firebase Offline Capabilities and addListenerForSingleValueEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486417/firebase-offline-capabilities-and-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent)

Comment: though that didn't help. I was able to "bypass" it with as boolean that won't reload the data in the array or table without UIRefreshed controller. thank you for your help though!!

Comment: For future questions, be sure to read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it increases the chance that someone can help you.