# Realtime Database not returning expected data

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to poll my realtime database every 3 seconds with the iOS SDK to retrieve the latest 5 message objects.

I use the following code:

```
let query = rtdb.child("event/ID/chat")
                .queryOrdered(byChild: "createdAt")
                .queryStarting(atValue: <TIMESTAMP>)
                .queryLimited(toFirst: 5)

query.observeOnce(of: eventType) { snapshot in }
```

Let's say I have the following (simplified) data in my db:

```
{
    id: 1,
    createdAt: 123456781
},
{
    id: 2,
    createdAt: 123456782
},
{
    id: 3,
    createdAt: 123456783
},
{
    id: 4,
    createdAt: 123456784
},
{
    id: 5,
    createdAt: 123456785
},
{
    id: 6,
    createdAt: 123456786
},
```

I start my query with the timestamp `123456787`. I then post another message with the timestamp `123456788`. My query does not pick it up. Why?

If I instead start my query with the timestamp `123456782`, it will return the messages with id `2, 3, 4, 5`.

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE

It's because of persistence being enabled. It just returns the locally cached data. That's stupid.

Comment: Are you ordering them ascending or descending?

Comment: I see you are also using observeOnce, surely that means the updates for your second message with the higher timestamp won't be seen unless it already exists before you observe the query results?

Comment: @TomBailey I don't specify order so it's ascending. Re your second point, I am calling the observer again. It gets called every 3 seconds.

Comment: Would it not be better to observe indefinitely? You should only receive updates if the underlying stream changes. As opposed to polling

Comment: @TomBailey I have an observer, but it's using way too much data transfer and costing tonnes. That's why I need to switch to polling.

Comment: From your update it sounds like you're hitting this behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486417/firebase-offline-capabilities-and-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent/34487195#34487195.  As a rule: don't mix disk persistence and single value event listeners, as they simply don't work well together.