# How to bypass the Firebase cache to refresh data?

Tags: android, firebase, caching, firebase-realtime-database

On an Android application which must works offline most of the time I need, when it's online, to do some synchronous operations but Firebase always take the value from the cache when I need the value in the servor , Here a exemple

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
        .child("Post")
        .child(UserChannel)
        .child("Post");
query.keepSynced(false);

query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
            Log.d(TAG, "Posts founded" );

            for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Posts thepost= snapshot.getValue(Posts.class);

                Log.d(TAG, "Post found");  

                ListPosts.add(thepost);
            }
        }else {
            Log.d(TAG, "  no post could be found.");              
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```

Here   I use addListenerForSingleValueEvent for load  posts from a specific user  , it works fine but if the user add a new post in the child and I try to reload all his posts  , the new post wont be loaded . I assume Firebase load the post from the cache   how can I bypass this the cache to load only from servor ?

Comment: `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` will return the latest value from the cache, and then refresh that cache with data from the server. If you call `keepSynced` in time, it will ensure the cache is up to date, but you might have a race condition here - in that the cache hasn't been updated yet when you call `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`. The solution is always the same: don't mix `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` with disk peristence, but use `addValueEventListener` and be prepared for multiple calls to `onDataChange`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34487195

Comment: I used your advice and founded the answer thanks you  !

Answer (score 3):

If you want your app to get data when a new child it's added use the following

```
        databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
            
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

Inside the `onChildAdded` add what you want to happen when a child it's added.
Be aware that `onChildAdded` gets the initial data and then will trigger again for last child added.
For additional information check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data)