# Firebase - query.get() vs addListenerForSingleValueEvent for single data read

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a very simple task to perform with Firebase Realtime Database on Android - Java: to read some data **once**.

After following the [official guides](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write), I came up with the following working method.

**Method #1:**

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
mDatabase.child("users").orderByKey().limitToFirst(1).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        // do something with the data here
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```

However, after researching [the API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#get()), I found another method that also works.

**Method #2:**

```
mDatabase.child("users").orderByKey().limitToFirst(1).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        DataSnapshot result = task.getResult();
        // do something with the data here              
    }
});
```

Both methods achieve very similar goals (to me), and I'm puzzled because there seems to be two different ways to complete one job.

Most articles I found are using the #1 method, but I've seen none explaining why they don't use the #2 method.

So are the methods different at all? Is there any reason to prefer one over another?

Comment: [This official document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events) may help you

Comment: You gave the same link as the one in my post. It doesn't answer my question

Comment: *firebaser here* Good find @FallingStar. I wrote an answer about the new API below, which hopefully explains. If not, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

The `get()` you found is a new API, that has not been completely finalized yet. Once finalized it mostly serves to address a race condition in the `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` API, which affects projects where disk persistence is enabled (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486417/firebase-offline-capabilities-and-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent/34487195#34487195) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63751187/firebase-realtime-database-reads-data-that-doesnt-exist/63754731#63754731)).

For the moment, I recommend to stick to the older existing API, at least until the `get()` API is finalized. Once it is officially released, we'll update the documentation to highlight the new API, and I'll update this answer.