# How to get the value from a node if we have a data from that node

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

what I want to do

- I have a firebase node as shown here: [image: here]
- my user will input a string(name), after that I will check if the (name)or(userinput) is available in the firebase by this code

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");            
ref.orderByChild("username").equalTo(userinputname).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            //username exist
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }     
}
```

If it is available then I want to get other data from that specific node in which the (name) is present..

simplified -
my user will input a username and pass, I have multiple username and pass in my DB so i want to first check if the username exists in DB if yes then i want the Pass which is in the DB to match it with the Password which is entered by the user to login

eg - if my user inputs username "Admin" which is avaiable in my DB, so I want to get the pass which is in that node which is "Admin123" and later I will check if the pass from DB matches the pass which is entered by the user to log him in the app

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Which part of the code you shared isn't working the way you expect it to?

Comment: THe code i shared is working fine , it checks if the value is present in the DB.. but i also want the data from the same node in which the value is found..as i wrote at last

Comment: Are you asking how to get the value from the data snapshot? If so: `dataSnapshot.val()` should do the trick, but also have a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events since you're using a query and that means it returns a list of data (even if there's only one result).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If my user inputs username "Admin" which is available in my DB, I want to get the pass that is in that node which is "Admin123" and later I will check if the pass from DB matches the pass which is entered by the user to log him in the app.

To be able to solve this problem, first, you have to perform a query that gets all the users where the value of the `username` field matches what the user types in the `userinputname` EditText. If the query returns at least a record, then you have to check the value of the `pass` field against the value `userinputpass` EditText. If there is a match, you can go ahead with the authentication, otherwise display a message, or do whatever you want.

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = db.child("users");
Query queryByUserName = usersRef.orderByChild("username").equalTo(userinputname);
queryByUserName.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                String pass = userSnapshot.child("pass").getValue(String.class);
                if(pass.equals(userinputpass)) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "Username and password are correct.");
                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", "The password is incorrect");
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

In the solution above, I have used [Query#get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#get()) and not [Query()#addListenerForSingleValueEvent()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#addListenerForSingleValueEvent(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)). Why? Is because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65653735/firebase-query-get-vs-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent-for-single-data-read).

While the above solution will work, please note that you should **never** store the user credentials in the way you do. Never! Storing passwords in cleartext is one of the worst security risks you can inflict on your users. So for avoiding that, I highly recommend you implement [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth).

Since you're using Java, I recommend you read the following article:

- [How to create a clean Firebase authentication using MVVM?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336)

If you consider at some point in time learning Kotlin, which I personally recommend, then please also check the following resources:

- [How to handle Firebase Authentication in clean architecture using Jetpack Compose?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-handle-firebase-authentication-in-clean-architecture-using-jetpack-compose-e9929c0e31f8)

And:

- [How to authenticate to Firebase using Google One Tap in Jetpack Compose?](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d)

**Edit:**

The above query requires an index. So in order to make it work, please add the following rules inside your Firebase console:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".indexOn": "username"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: {Index not defined, add ".indexOn": "username", for path "/users", to the rules}

getting this error via Log.d

Comment: That means that it works, but there is only one thing that remains to be done, which is to [add an index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60848233/what-is-the-correct-way-to-add-indexon-rule-in-firebase-realtime-database). Add it and tell me if it works, ok?

Comment: add an index ... sorry i didnt get it .. can u show me

Comment: What didn't you get? What have you tried and didn't worked out?

Comment: I dont know how to add an index.....so i didnt try anything, can u please tell me how to add index and where

Comment: If you have any other questions that derive from this one, then they should be considered newer questions that should be added separately, here on StackOverflow. Since you're new, I'll also provide you with the rules. So please check my updated answer. Try them and tell me if it works now.

Comment: Hey here. Have you tried my edited solution above, does it work?

Comment: There are no error now but now even if i input the correct unsername and pass it logs incorrect password in the logcat

Comment: No, It worked ! i was checking the wrong pass, Thankyou sooo much !

Comment: Good to hear that :) You're very welcome, cheers!