# How long for addListenerForSingleValueEvent to update?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase, in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) for the Realtime Database, describes 3 methods for reading:

1. get() reaches out to the cloud and gets a value;
2. addValueEventListener() updates immediately; and
3. addListenerForSingleValueEvent() updates, umm, hmm, when exactly?

That 3rd option "works", it gets updates, but when? Experimenting with it, I sometimes saw it updating after 2 minutes, sometimes 30, once I shut down my laptop and went to bed, came back the next day and it still hasn't.

Does anyone know what one can expect?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` was the original method in the Firebase SDK to retrieve a value once. Over time we found that it had one edge-case that might be exactly what some folks want, but is the unwanted behavior for the vast majority of users. I documented that here: [Firebase Offline Capabilities and addListenerForSingleValueEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486417/firebase-offline-capabilities-and-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent)

For new code, you should use `get()` and only consider `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` if the above edge-case is exactly what you want (which should be *extremely* rare).