# Firebase Database differentiate between online and offline data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know that the Firebase Realtime Database provides offline support, but how can I differentiate between data provided by an online connection or local offline changes?

Comment: If your goal is to only ensure you're reading online data, then this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35454652/how-to-bypass-the-firebase-cache-to-refresh-data-in-android-app

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

The Firebase Database provides a specific method to know if a client is connected or not.

Google wrote a handy [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state) on that topic.

From the provided link:

> **Detecting Connection State**
>
> For many presence-related features, it is useful for a client to know when it is online or offline. Firebase Realtime Database clients provide a special location at `/.info/connected` which is updated every time the client's connection state changes.
>
> ```
> DatabaseReference connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
> connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
>   @Override
>   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
>     boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
>     if (connected) {
>       System.out.println("connected");
>     } else {
>       System.out.println("not connected");
>     }
>   }
>   @Override
>   public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
>     System.err.println("Listener was cancelled");
>   }
> });
> ```
>
> `/.info/connected` is a boolean value which is not synchronized between clients because the value is dependent on the state of the client. In other words, if one client reads `/.info/connected` as false, this is no guarantee that a separate client will also read false.
>
> On Android, Firebase automatically manages connection state to reduce bandwidth and battery usage. When a client has no active listeners, no pending write or `onDisconnect` operations, and is not explicitly disconnected by the `goOffline` method, Firebase closes the connection after 60 seconds of inactivity.

Knowing if your client is connected to the database will help differentiate between data provided from online and offline storage. I am pretty sure there is no specific way to see if a `DataSnapshot` comes from online or offline data.

Comment: This is not a working approach. Just tested it, by loading a value after the "onConnected" callback, and first a cached (offline) value is returned, a while later the new (online) value is returned.

Comment: The 60 second disconnect if no active listeners was something I wasn't aware of! I'm listening to .info/connected reference to determine if my client has an internet/firebase connection, and showing a network error if false. It seems firebase doesn't consider a listener on .info/connected as an active listener in this case.